# Remove leading whitespace in a wordpress customfield?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have thousands of entries in a wordpress site with a custom field called `description` and inside all of them, I have a leading white space, like this:

```
" bla, bla, bla"
```

And I need to remove all that white spaces like this:

```
"bla, bla, bla"
```

I was trying to do this `$sql = "UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta set description = ltrim(rtrim(description))";` but is not working.

phpmyadmin says: `# 1054 - Unknown 'description' column in 'field list'`

Is it possible, and or how?

Comment: Use `trim` to make it.

Comment: How is it not working? Have you tried running it directly from the mysql command line or in phpMyAdmin? Both `ltrim()` and `rtrim()` are valid mysql functions.

Comment: @jeroen phpmyadmin says: `# 1054 - Unknown 'description' column in 'field list'`. Edited above.

Comment: @Alex The error says it all, are you sure the column is called `description`?

Comment: @jeroen the column of custom fields in `wp_postmeta` is `meta_key` and that's that column that contains the customfield `description`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the TRIM function of MySQL ([See reference](https://database.guide/how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-mysql/))

```
UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta set description = TRIM(description);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    $wpdb->postmeta
SET 
    description = RTRIM(description);
```

Try to write **trim** in Capital